# Possible to free Context from Singleton in Android to prevent memory leak

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks

I'm maintaining a legacy project where I can't do much refactoring due to limitations. But I just found a possible memory leak in below scenario.

Pass a Fragment to a singleton class

```
Foo.getInstance().setBar(fragment);
```

Assuming the static instance lives longer then we need it, Is it a good approach to null it in onDestroy() method in that fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Foo.getInstance().setBar(null);//to prevent memory leak
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I'm new to memory leak area, so correct me if there is anything wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`WeakReference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) in the singleton

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your reply.  Is this a common practice for all variables in singleton pattern to be WeakReferenced or only those Objects that consumes large chunk of memory.

Comment: Weak references are used on objects that should not be owned by the referencing object and you expect the referencing object to last much longer than the one (or all if there are more) that owns the referenced object. It should not matter how large the object is. It is sometimes hard to distinguish when that is the case but in this scenario it is obvious: the fragment is destroyed by someone else but the singleton lives on. Btw. if you can use any context and not necessarily the fragment, use the application context; you don't need to worry with weak references then.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive answer, it was very helpful. I have also seen code with nullify objects to free up memory, can this approach be replaced by WeakReference solution? Any other concerns need to take into account? Many thanks!

Comment: @WenChao That approach can also be used but you risk memory leak when for some reason you didn't expect (eg. exception) the object is not nulled. On the other hand, weak reference is cleared only when GC collects the object so if you need to keep exact lifetime, `null` may be preferred. Or you can combine both approaches.